# Delphi7 Remove/Restore MAINICON from Project

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi7 you can assign/load an icon to a project. After every compilation your application has the assigned icon. I would like to delete/restore the icon back to the original Delphi7 Icon. I can't find a button/option for this. I also tried deleting the .res file but no luck.
Any Ideas?

Comment: isn't there a project Image option ..? you should be able to change the Icon at the Icon at the project level...

Comment: in Delphi7 I can only load/assign another icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon is stored in the .res file.
If you delete/rename your .res file with the project open in the IDE, maybe the .res data is already loaded and then will be saved again to the new .res.

Anyway, if excluding the .res file is not solving your problem, you can open the .res file with a resource editor tool ([XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) for example) and export/change/delete the MAINICON resource as you want.

Comment: Actually, closing the project, deleting the .res, and reopening the project causes the icon to be restored for me. You will get a warning message saying the .res file was recreated, and note this may reset your version info too.